# Gets an error using the post function in firebase using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, axios

I joined the site a few days ago.
I'm new here.

I have a problem that I can not solve. I built a function in Nodejs, every time I run the function I want to get information from the server.

On the client side I have this function, which I run, and then save the data, here no problem.

```
export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => (dispatch) => {

    axios.post('/realtimeConversations', user)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))

}
```

I have a series of axios, when I use this line, I run a server-side function.

```
app.post('/realtimeConversations', FBAuth, getRealtimeConversations);
```

This is the function on the server side, I have a collection, which I want to access according to details I send from the client. After I have done the calculations I want, I want to return the end result.

```
exports.getRealtimeConversations = (req, res) => {

    db.collection('conversations')
        .where('user_uid_1', 'in', [req.body.uid_1, req.body.uid_2])
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

            const conversations = [];

            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

                if (
                    (doc.data().user_uid_1 == req.body.uid_1 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == req.body.uid_2)
                    ||
                    (doc.data().user_uid_1 == req.body.uid_2 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == req.body.uid_1)
                ) {
                    conversations.push(doc.data())
                }

            });
            console.log(conversations);
            return res.json(conversations);
        })
}
```

I do not know why but I get that I have a 404 error, I am completely new to it, I think I have a logical error in the server side function, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried requesting url from cURL or Postman (https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes in the postman it gives me a 500 error

Comment: then the problem might not come from axios, However, 404 error might mean that the url is wrong. check if your url is the right one as it may not be credential problems since it shall, in this case return 403 Forbidden or 401 Unauthorized instead.